# Unity's Transform.Translate moves on z axis when translating on x

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, orientation

The Translate function in Unity is showing some weird behaviour in my project today which i've never experienced before. When I try to translate my player to the left with either `Vector3.left` or `new Vector3(-1, 0, 0)` it also goes -1 on the Z axis. The same happens when I go to the right, in this case it moves +1 on the Z axis.

I've tried a lot of things including:

- `transform.Translate(-1, 0, 0);`
- `transform.Translate(Vector3.left);`
- `transform.position += Vector3.left;'
- `transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x-1, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);`
- I've even tried stuff like `transform.Translate(-1, 0, 1);' without success
- The problem is not in the orientation. `Space.world` or default RelativeTo parameter `Space.self` don't fix it.

Can anyone help me further with this? I'm out of idea's...

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
```

instead

Comment: this kind of fixes it but i need it to move by exactly one unit. Could you maybe also explain why this is a solution?